# Reverse iteration in Julia

Tags: iteration, julia, reverse-iterator

Yesterday I had occasion to want to iterate over a collection in reverse order. I found the `reverse` function, but this does not return an iterator, but actually creates a reversed collection.

Apparently, there used to be a `Reverse` iterator, which was [removed](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/4590) several years ago. I can also find [reference](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/6780) to something (a type?) called `Order.Reverse`, but that does not seem to apply to my question.

The [`Iterators.jl`](https://github.com/JuliaCollections/Iterators.jl) package has many interesting iteration patterns, but apparently not reverse iteration.

I can of course use the `reverse` function, and in some cases, for example `reverse(eachindex(c))` which returnes a reversed iterator, but I would prefer a general reverse iterator.

Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**UPDATE FOR JULIA 1.0+**

You can now use `Iterators.reverse` to reverse a limited subset of types. For example:

```
julia> Iterators.reverse(1:10)
10:-1:1

julia> Iterators.reverse(CartesianIndices(zeros(2,3))) |> collect
2×3 Array{CartesianIndex{2},2}:
 CartesianIndex(2, 3)  CartesianIndex(2, 2)  CartesianIndex(2, 1)
 CartesianIndex(1, 3)  CartesianIndex(1, 2)  CartesianIndex(1, 1)

julia> Iterators.Reverse([1,1,2,3,5]) |> collect
5-element Array{Int64,1}:
 5
 3
 2
 1
 1

# But not all iterables support it (and new iterables don't support it by default):
julia> Iterators.reverse(Set(1:2)) |> collect
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching iterate(::Base.Iterators.Reverse{Set{Int64}})
```

Note that this only works for types that have specifically defined reverse iteration. That is, they have specifically defined `Base.iterate(::Iterators.Reverse{T}, ...)` where T is the custom type.  So it's not fully general purpose (for the reasons documented below), but it does work for any type that supports it.

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

Jeff's comment when he removed the reverse iterator three years ago (in [the issue you linked](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/4590)) is just as relevant today:

> I am highly in favor of deleting this since it simply does not work. Unlike everything else in iterator.jl it depends on indexing, not iteration, and doesn't even work on everything that's indexable (for example UTF8String). I hate having landmines like this in Base.

At the most basic level, iterators only know how to do three things: start iteration, get the next element, and check if the iteration is done. In order to create an iterator that doesn't allocate using these primitives, you'd need an O(n^2) algorithm: walk through the whole iterator, counting as you go, until you find the last element. Then walk the iterator *again*, only this time stopping at the penultimate element.  Sure it doesn't allocate, but it'll be *way* slower than just collecting the iterator into an array and then indexing backwards.  And it'll be completely broken for one-shot iterators (like `eachline`).  So it is simply not possible to create an efficient general reverse iterator.

Note that `reverse(eachindex(c))` does not work in general:

```
julia> reverse(eachindex(sprand(5,5,.2)))
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching reverse(::CartesianRange{CartesianIndex{2}})
```

One alternative that will still work with offset arrays is `reverse(linearindices(c))`.

Comment: I _did_ read that comment, but I didn't take it as meaning that reverse iteration was infeasible. And Stefan Karpinski's following comment didn't give off that impression either. Regardless, your arguments make a lot of sense, but would it be impractical to support reverse iteration for some subset of collections? I see that Python does have something like that: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed

Comment: No, it wouldn't be impractical at all.  It's just that nobody has defined such an interface yet — we just need someone to do that work and I have a feeling it'd be accepted.  Ref. https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/4590#issuecomment-26684029

Comment: I see. Well, that answers my question.

Comment: [As of Julia 1.8](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/42225), `eachline` actually supports reverse-order iteration for seekable files.